# Unable to import scapy.all in python while root user

Tags: python, scapy

I have a python file named "**test_module.py**" with the code

`from scapy.all import *`

and when i execute the file with `python test_module.py` the module is getting **imported successfully** but when I run the file using the command `sudo python test_module.py` it is saying the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_module.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
ImportError: No module named scapy.all
```

System info:-

> Linux mint 20

> Python 2.7.18

So, Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Did you do

```
sudo python -m pip install scapy
```

first ? your issue is likely just having two separate environments

Comment: Error:- ``/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
``

Comment: Just install pip using get-pip then.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps, try :

```
pip install scapy
```

```
import sys

# and take the correct Path to your scapy , example :

sys.path.insert(1, '/home/Your NAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/')
```